# Merging categories on Google Sheets but data will be unclear

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Sorry in advanced for bad English. I have 15+ rows and 15+ columns. I need to merge cells in a spreadsheet but data will be unclear after merging. Is there a formula/function I can use to clarify my merge? Thank you in advance.

[Please view example spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1H-K7vwGy_tzyeMMZD2pHxvAGTUwIBJlzoq1Tpa4uYwo/edit?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible using only formula. Formulas can't do anything to formatting like merging cells and applying colors to text. But here's a script you can use to begin with. You may modify it to apply font color.

**Try:**

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var sourceData = sourceSheet.getRange(2, 1, sourceSheet.getLastRow() - 1, sourceSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();

  //Add name to each column, add here if you have more columns
  sourceData.forEach(function (x) {
    x[2] = x[1] + ":\n" + x[2]
    x[3] = x[1] + ":\n" + x[3]
  });

  var array = sourceData,
    hash = {},
    i, j,
    result,
    item,
    key;

  for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    item = array[i];
    key = item[0].toString();
    if (!hash[key]) {
      hash[key] = item.slice();
      continue;
    }
    for (j = 1; j < item.length; j++) hash[key][j] = hash[key][j] + "\n" + item[j];
  }

  result = Object.values(hash);
  destSheet.getRange(2, 1, result.length, result[0].length).setValues(result);
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Reference:**
[How to merge an array of arrays with duplicate at index 0 into one array javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57035054/how-to-merge-an-array-of-arrays-with-duplicate-at-index-0-into-one-array-javascr)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Feel free to ask if you have questions! :)

Comment: Hi Logan, sorry I am not good with javascript. I attempted to use your code, but I am having an issue. Thank you in advance. Google Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DC3g9q50qVV8_RsyandH59SkYHGB031HmJSMHarY0bc/edit?resourcekey=0-RDw_iO_MwW6gvaR7yYedeg#gid=1356400727    Pastebin: https://pastebin.com/RgSvtvRi

Comment: *Updated Pastebin link: https://pastebin.com/GYvKZ1jM

Comment: Sorry if this doesn't help, I assumed you had some javascipt knowledge so I just provided a starting code which you can modify to suit your specific details. Is your data dynamic?

Comment: Yes, my data is dynamic since it is utilizing an import range and pulling from another Google Sheet.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with this formula, adapt the column range in the MAP function if necessary:

```
={UNIQUE('raw data'!A2:A),
SCAN(,UNIQUE('raw data'!A2:A),
LAMBDA(x,city, BYCOL(IFNA(FILTER ({'raw data'!B2:B,
MAP('raw data'!C2:G,LAMBDA(a,IF(a="","",INDEX('raw data'!B:B,ROW(a))&":"&CHAR(10)&a)))},'raw data'!A2:A=city,'raw data'!A2:A<>"")),LAMBDA(col,JOIN(CHAR(10)&CHAR(10),col)))))}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried following your formula, but I am getting an error. If you don't mind, could you please take a look? https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wYaH9h2UXPkoiwjFd997rQ3FLcU0uuhVof_ia9BBVaU/edit?resourcekey=0-32fYwrJfN8xqIo699O_iUg#gid=701742957